# How to copy a depth image to a color image?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I try to blit a depth image to a smaller image (the objective is to blur the image).

The problem is that when I execute `vkCmdBlitImage` with `VK_FILTER_LINEAR`, I have this message : `If the format of srcImage is a depth, stencil, or depth stencil then filter must be VK_FILTER_NEAREST`. I guess that I first need to copy the depth image to a color image.

I tried then `vkCmdBlitImage` with `VK_FILTER_NEAREST` but I have this error : `If one of srcImage and dstImage images has a format of depth, stencil or depth stencil, the other one must have exactly the same format`.

I have the same problem with `vkCmdCopyImage`.

My question is : can I copy a depth image to a color image without creating a pipeline ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly copy depth data into a color image. You *can* copy the depth data to a buffer via `vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer`, then copy that data into an image with `vkCmdCopyBufferToImage`.

Comment: Is this operation costly ? Do you think that is better to attach a color image and a fragment shader to the pass that create the depth buffer or to use a transitional buffer ?

Comment: On an Intel HD Graphics 520, my performance are : using directly depth images -> 44 FPS, using a fragment shader to create the color image with the depth image -> 23 FPS, using a transitional buffer as you suggest -> 35 FPS. Your solution seems to be better than using a fragment shader.